# Problem with getting correct StopIndex of a Token in ANTLR 4 Parse Tree

Tags: antlr, antlr4

**Goal**

I have been trying to write a simple step-by-step reduction algorithm, which would simplify given logic equations and show steps of simplification. To start with, I decided to implement a reduction in parentheses. To retrieve all nesting parentheses I use **ANTLR**.

**Materials**

I wrote a simple **grammar** for logic expressions trying to use a left-recursive feature of ANTLRv4:

**Binary.g4**

```
grammar Binary;

expr
    : LPAREN expr RPAREN   #ParExpr
    | NOT expr             #NotBlock
    | expr AND expr        #AndBlock
    | expr OR expr         #OrBlock
    | expr IMP expr        #ImplBlock
    | expr EQ expr         #EqualBlock
    | expr XOR expr        #XorBlock
    | INT                  #Int
    | VAR                  #Var
    | WS                   #WS
    ;

NOT: '¬';

AND: '∧';

OR: '∨';

IMP: '⇒';

EQ: '≡';

XOR: '⊕';

LPAREN: '(';

RPAREN: ')';

INT: '0' | '1';

VAR: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z') ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')*;

WS: [ \r\n\t] + -> skip;
```

My idea was to walk a generated by ANTLR parse tree with a listener and fire my events when exiting **ParExpr** nodes. There I would retrieve the content of parenthesis by using CharStream and simplify it.

**ParenthesisListener.java**

```java
public class ParenthesisListener extends BinaryBaseListener {

    private boolean changed = false;

    @Override
    public void exitParExpr(BinaryParser.ParExprContext ctx) {
        final CharStream input = ctx.start.getInputStream();

        if (!changed) {
            final int a = ctx.start.getStartIndex();
            final int b = ctx.stop.getStopIndex();

            final Interval interval = new Interval(a, b);

            final String branch = input.getText(interval);


            // Simplifying value in "branch"
            // If "branch" value changes, make "changed" variable true
       }

       System.out.println(input.getText(new Interval(ctx.start.getStartIndex(), ctx.stop.getStopIndex())));
    }

}
```

**Problem**

Quite unexpectedly, it appeared to be problematic to retrieve the contents of **ParExprContext** with CharStream. After debugging the code there seems to be a problem in **ctx.stop.getStopIndex()**, as it returns lower value than needed.

For example, by giving the code expression like

> ((A∧B)∨((A∧B)∧B))⇒B

it yields such results:

```
(A∧B)
((A∧B)∨((A∧B
(((A∧B)∨((A∧B)
```

**Question**

Therefore, I would like to ask, how to get indexes of given Intervals right? I guess there is a mistake in my grammar, which leads to these unexpected results. The *AST* for expression above is:

[image: parsed tree from expression ((A∧B)∨((A∧B)∧B))⇒B]

I am ready to provide any extra materials needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your grammar and listener code, and wrote a program to run it. I also printed out the token stream and parse tree for your input. It's producing exactly what one would expect. However, what I got in the output from the println() in the listener output, shown below, differs from what you provided in your question. The output from my program is the same result for Java and C#, token indices from 0 to 19 (the EOF token). I can only think that maybe you are using an older tool and runtime. Make sure you are using 4.8 of the Antlr Tool and runtime.

```
parse completed.
Token 0 7 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL (
Token 1 7 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL (
Token 2 10 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL A
Token 3 2 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL ∧
Token 4 10 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL B
Token 5 8 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL )
Token 6 3 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL ∨
Token 7 7 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL (
Token 8 7 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL (
Token 9 10 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL A
Token 10 2 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL ∧
Token 11 10 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL B
Token 12 8 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL )
Token 13 2 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL ∧
Token 14 10 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL B
Token 15 8 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL )
Token 16 8 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL )
Token 17 4 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL ⇒
Token 18 10 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL B
Token 19 -1 channel DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL <EOF>

( implBlock
  ( parExpr
    ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=0 txt=( tt=7
    )
    ( orBlock
      ( parExpr
        ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=1 txt=( tt=7
        )
        ( andBlock
          ( var
            ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=2 txt=A tt=10
          ) )
          ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=3 txt=∧ tt=2
          )
          ( var
            ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=4 txt=B tt=10
        ) ) )
        ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=5 txt=) tt=8
      ) )
      ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=6 txt=∨ tt=3
      )
      ( parExpr
        ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=7 txt=( tt=7
        )
        ( andBlock
          ( parExpr
            ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=8 txt=( tt=7
            )
            ( andBlock
              ( var
                ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=9 txt=A tt=10
              ) )
              ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=10 txt=∧ tt=2
              )
              ( var
                ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=11 txt=B tt=10
            ) ) )
            ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=12 txt=) tt=8
          ) )
          ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=13 txt=∧ tt=2
          )
          ( var
            ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=14 txt=B tt=10
        ) ) )
        ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=15 txt=) tt=8
    ) ) )
    ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=16 txt=) tt=8
  ) )
  ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=17 txt=⇒ tt=4
  )
  ( var
    ( DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL i=18 txt=B tt=10
) ) )

Start 1 Stop 5 (A∧B)
Start 8 Stop 12 (A∧B)
Start 7 Stop 15 ((A∧B)∧B)
Start 0 Stop 16 ((A∧B)∨((A∧B)∧B))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @kaby76! I checked the version of ANTLR tool and runtime I'm using, and it wasn't 4.8. I now upgraded to it, but there seems to be another problem, as my listener now only walks context with indexes 1 to 5 and 0 to 18. If it's not a problem, could you please provide your code of a listener? I feel I miss something in mine. Thank you!

Comment: My code can be found here https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/Binary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out, what caused an error. I looked through your code and it truly is quite similar to mine. I feel there might be a problem with the version of my ANTLR tool. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help and time! Really appreciate it!